# Get-ADUser : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Identity'. The Identity property on the argument is null or empty error

Tags: powershell

I am new to powershell and am stuck on a script I'm trying to make. I have a list of usernames from our system network that I am trying to filter. They are the data folders for each of the users in active directory and the names of each of the folders are the samaccountname for each user. I am trying to filter these folders so I can delete old users' folders that have been disabled for a year or more. I exported the names of all of the folders to a text file and when I try to access each user in the file it throws an error on powershell:

```
Get-ADUser : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'System.Object[]'.
At line:2 char:5
+     Get-ADUser $user sAMAccountName, DistinguishedName | Select sAMAc ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-ADUser], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUser

Get-ADUser : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Identity'. The Identity property on the argument is null or empty.
At line:2 char:16
+     Get-ADUser $user sAMAccountName, DistinguishedName | Select sAMAc ...
+                ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-ADUser], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUser
```

I was wondering if anyone knew how I could fix this or possibly cast the system.object[] to an aduser object.

Here is the portion of my script that isn't working:

```
$users = Get-Content -Path \\beans\Support\TC\SummerTesting\beansUsers.txt
ForEach($user in $users){
    Get-ADUser $user sAMAccountName, DistinguishedName | Select sAMAccountName, DistinguishedName | Where {$_.DistinguishedName -like "*ou=ou here"}
}
```

An example of the text file:

user1

user2

user3

Comment: Did you read the Documentation for `Get-ADUser` ? the `Identity` Parameter accept one of this options: "distinguished name","objectGUID","objectSid" and "sAMAccountName", as seen in your txt file example, `$user` will be let's say "user1", probably a samAccountName,  so why do you add  the "sAMAccountName, DistinguishedName" after it? remove it... leave only the `Get-ADUser $user | Select sAMAccountName[...]`

Comment: I was just testing things out and forgot to delete that. The issue still has happens without that.

Comment: You can filter at the first call: `Get-ADUser -Filter "Name -eq '$user'" -SearchBase 'OU=blag,DC=blah'`

Comment: That didn't work but this seemed to at least output what I wanted:
$users = Get-Content -Path \\path here
ForEach($user in $users){
    
    Get-ADUser -Identity $user.Trim() | Select sAMAccountName, DistinguishedName | Where {$_.DistinguishedName -like "*ou=blah"}
}
but then it printed out this error message:
Get-ADUser : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Identity'. The Identity property on the argument is null or empty.
At line:2 char:26

Comment: Does the file with usernames have these empty lines as you show us? Then filter these out first.

Comment: No it doesn't. I'm also trimming it to remove extra space